# Oracle Forms - Just another ORA-12154 error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, tnsnames

---The problem is solved, the Oracle Forms has its own otnsnames.ora file, located in NET80\ADMIN---

I have Oracle and Oracle Forms Runbtime installed on mi PC (windows). THe whole stuff connects to another machine where the database is set.

At Oracle Forms Runtime lauching, I have an ORA-12154 error.

Here are the things I checked (and I really don't know what to check more, that's why I'm asking here)

-Checking my Oracles configuration files :

```
#tnsnames.ora
BOL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = sajama)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = BOL)
    )
  )

#sqlnet.ora
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, ONAMES, HOSTNAME)
```

The host "sajama" is declared in hosts file.

-Checking the connexion with the database. I'm able to connect with tnsping to BOL, and i can connect to the database via Sqlplus with the same identifiers and SID that I enter in Oracle Forms.

I didn't found any information about a specific Oracle Forms configuration file, nor information about this specific problem on the net...

I actually already have another machine connecting to the same database, and their tnsmanes.ora and sqlnet.ora are exactly the sames. Moreover, the Oracle Forms scripts are installed on the Oracle database machine, it's then the same file that is lauched from the two computers. And, it works on the secund one.

Does someone have a clue? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is Forms picking up the same `tnsnames.ora` file as SQL*Plus etc.? I seem to recall it has its own, possibly under its own `config` directory, and that would be a sample by default. But I'm not sure...

Comment: Yes they do have, that was the problem, it's now solved! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the TNS file is located under ...\Middleware\asinst_1\config